# My partial view does not refresh after AJAX call

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am having an issue not able to refresh my Partial view.

my cshtml page page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#btncreate').click(function () {
          var projectid = $("#txtprojectid").val();
          $.ajax({
              url: '/Projects/CreateFinanceItems?pid=' + Id,
              datatype: 'json',
              type: "POST",
              success: function (response) {
                  alert("record created successfully");
                  if (response != null) {
                      window.close();
                      refreshpartial();
                  }
              }
          })
      });

      function refreshpartial()
      {
          $.ajax({
              url: '/Projects/PartialItem?id=' + "Test",
              datatype: 'json',
              success: function (response) {
                  $("#displayproContainer").html(response);
              },
              error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
              }
          })
      }
    });        
    </script>
```

I can see record created successfully alert message, but when it goes to refreshpartial method my partialview does not refresh with Added data. I put the alert in success function it does not hit.

Partialview DIV ID #displayproContainer

```
$("#displayproContainer").html(response);
```

Controller code

```
  [OutputCache(Duration = 0)]
        public PartialViewResult PartialItem(string id)
        {
            // Logic to Insert data
            return PartialView(viewModel);
        }
```

Something I am missing here?

Comment: Omit this line: `window.close();`

Comment: Thank you the issue is with datatype: json, I removed that its hitting success, but my partial view does not update. any Idea?

Comment: Did you try `dataType: "html"` in the ajax, inside refresh partial method?

Comment: Yes I did try tthat no luck

Comment: Voted to undelete this answer, as it can give the Question ideas about how to solve this without using JavaScript.  I remain in agreement that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58447804/jquery-autocomplete-using-typeahead-suggestion-does-not-display-after-a-successf/58457787?noredirect=1#comment103253279_58457787 duplicate answer should be deleted

Comment: What response is returned from `CreateFinanceItems` action method?  Please comment this if clause `if (response != null)` for a moment and set a break point in `PartialItem` action method to make sure the second ajax works properly.